# Using wildcards in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess, wildcard

I have found a couple answers that solve the problem of passing wildcards through Popen, but I can't seem to get those solutions to work for my particular case.

I have a project that will merge an audio and video file when a button is pressed, and I need to use subprocess.Popen to execute the command I want:

```
mergeFile = "ffmpeg -i /home/pi/Video/* -i /home/pi/Audio/test.wav -acodec copy -vcodec copymap 0:v -map 1:a /home/pi/Test/output.mkv"
proc= subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(mergeFiles), shell=True)
```

I basically want to take whatever file is in my Video folder (my project downloads videos from a camera and the name of the file changes every time a new video is saved) and merge the audio from a separate "Audio" folder and then save that file to yet another folder.

I have tried setting the shell to true, and nothing works.

I also don't know how the glob module would help me in this scenario.

Comment: Take out `shlex.split()`. Just pass the string itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the `shlex.split()`. When used in conjunction with `shell=True`, it means that only the string `ffmpeg` is treated as a script, and that the other components of your command line are passed as arguments to that script (which it never looks at / reads).

```
mergeFile = "ffmpeg -i /home/pi/Video/* -i /home/pi/Audio/test.wav -acodec copy -vcodec copymap 0:v -map 1:a /home/pi/Test/output.mkv"
proc = subprocess.Popen(mergeFile, shell=True)
```

---

A better-practice alternative that still uses `shell=True` (if you're actually parameterizing the directory names and filenames) might be:

```
mergeFile=[
    'ffmpeg -i "$1"/* -i "$2" -acodec copy -vcodec copymap 0:v -map 1:a "$3"',
    '_',                          # placeholder for $0
    "/home/pi/Video",             # directory for $1 -- can use a variable here
    "/home/pi/Audio/test.wav",
    "/home/pi/Test/output.mkv",
]
subprocess.Popen(mergeFile, shell=True)
```

...in which case the *script itself* is constant (and can't have its meaning changed by values injected via filenames or other parameters), but out-of-band data can be provided.

---

Even better than that is to stop using `shell=True` altogether. Consider:

```
import subprocess, glob

mergeFile=[
  'ffmpeg', '-i',
] + (glob.glob('/home/pi/Video/*') or ['/home/pi/Video/*']) + [
  '-i', '/home/pi/Audio/test.wav',
  '-acodec', 'copy',
  '-vcodec', 'copymap', '0:v',
  '-map', '1:a1',
  '/home/pi/Test/output.mkv' 
]
subprocess.Popen(mergefile)
```

The `or ['/home/pi/Video/*']` exists to cause the same error message you'd get with a shell if no files matching the glob exist. Obviously, you could just abort in that case as well.

Comment: Using `shlex.split()` in conjunction with `subprocess.Popen()` is a common idiom (with `shell=False`) -- just a really unfortunate one, IMHO. The *whole point* of using `shell=False` is to allow an explicit, unambiguous argument list (with exactly the filenames and other arguments you want) to be passed -- when you start forming your argument list into a string and then having a library parse that string, you're suddenly adding ambiguity where you had the option of having none.

Comment: ...and, to be clear, `shell=True` *is* ambiguous, prone to security bugs, and otherwise a bad idea. Consider what happens if instead of hardcoding one of the filenames in your `mergeFile` string you were getting it from `os.listdir()` of an uploads directory -- unless you're careful about how you create that string, a file created with `touch $'$(rm -rf ~)\'$(rm -rf ~)\''.wav`could have *very* unfortunate side effects.

Comment: `shlex.split()` is a first line of defense against shell injection attacks and I think that's why it can be preferred over `shell=True`. It doesn't catch everything and you can end up passing shell meta-characters as parameters to confusing results, but it still beats the alternative.

Comment: @tdelaney, "the alternative" (in the sense of the best-available alternative, at least) isn't `shell=True` -- the alternative is passing an explicit argv array. `shell=False` with `shlex.split()` does save you from `$(...)`, but it doesn't help with a file named `foo --execute-trigger-command=...`; passing *all* parameters out-of-band (even with `shell=True`, as with `['script using "$1" and "$2" here', '_', paramater_one, parameter_two]`) is the Right Thing; anything less is a compromise.

Comment: (Granted, `--execute-trigger-command=` is a bit contrived, but for our current case of ffmpeg, there are numerous options/commands that could be used to SSH to resources using the current user's agent credentials; retrieve content from the local network; or otherwise make trouble -- see https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html).